# Android ProgressDialog does not dismiss

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am trying to write code which can, for example, show an `AlertDialog` message after 5 seconds and during these 5 seconds I want to show a `ProgressDialog`.

I wrote the code but `ProgressDialog` does not dismiss.
This is the source code:

```
ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CameraPreview.this,
        "Please wait ...", "Downloading Image ...", true);

ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
ringProgressDialog.hide();

AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        ringProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            diaBox1.show();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (ringProgressDialog != null) {
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            // b.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

};
task.execute((Void[]) null);
```

Comment: Is onPostExecute called?

Comment: What is your diaBox1? Your code works if you don't call `diaBox1.show()`.

Comment: if your `diaBox1` is GUI element (which I think is) then your code would not work because you are not suppose to modify GUI from background task....